# redrawing an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I just started with C, but I had some knowledge of PHP, so I decided to do some 'more complicated' stuff, as for a beginner :)

I used two nested loops to print an 50x50 array. It isn't very slow, but I included a movement with arrow keys to it to move one symbol, X (player) around the array. Every time a move is made, whole array needs to be refreshed, which I did by:

```
system("cls");
for(x=0;x<50;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<50;y++)
    {
         printf("%c",table[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which is very sloppy solution and whole array 'blinks' while it refreshes after every move.

Is there any more efficient way of doing that in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably have to use some sort of shell graphics library like **ncurses** to move stuff around your array without it blinking when you redraw it. There's not really a simple way to avoid that when you're just using printf to display your grid as output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Windows (because of the cls).

Maybe ANSI.SYS escape sequences are the simplest way without a library.

You can probably avoid flickering if you move the cursor and overwrite the display contents without clearing the old contents.

Comment: Oops. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code, that doesn't work anymore (unless you've got NT or older version of windows). But that page mentions a Win32 Console API. I can't test it, sitting in front of a linux box - maybe the escape sequences still work, but without an ANSI.SYS "driver"?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on "Reading and Writing Blocks of Characters and Attributes" with the Win32 Console:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Edit: explained the link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.